# PHP y MySql Array

Tags: php, mysql

Me encuentro haciendo una Consulta

```html
$Consulta1 = mysqli_query($enlace, "SELECT  SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta) FROM clima_laboral_estructura AS cle WHERE  (cle.Total_Respuesta  <1.5 )");
 
$total1 = mysqli_fetch_row($Consulta1);
echo "La cantidad de registros es: ".$total1[0];
```

Al imprimir me arroja el resultado correcto **La cantidad de registros es: 2.7**

Sin embargo cuando uso var_dump($total1);

me arroja

array (size=1)
  0 => string '2.7' (length=3)

Obviamente no puedo utilizar esta variable para operaciones aritmeticas, y por duda y falta de conocimiento, pregunto

¿Puede convertirse esa variable al valor arrojado numerico, es decir decimal, float, real? y si no es mucho abuso, que metodo deberia usarse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Intenta convertirlo de esta manera:

```
$total = (float) $total1[0];
```

Comment: Muy agradecido, Pero, ya lo había probado, lo hice, antes, en medio, y después de la función y antes del echo, y aun sigue siendo un string

Comment: Ahora obtén el tipo gettype($total), ¿Aún no puedes realizar operaciones con $total?

Comment: http://codepad.org/ldy3hJyt aqui esta el codigo, puedes verlo con plena confianza. y a menos que la este declarando mal. sigue arrojandome el mismo resultado.  

array (size=1)
  0 => string '2.7' (length=3)

Comment: Intenta hacer la prueba con una operación sencilla, por ejemplo: $total = $total2[0] * 2; Con var_dump sólo obtienes la variable que deseas vaciar la información.

Comment: Ok, si ahora me dice que es un float, pero, me borra el contenido.

La cantidad de registros es: La cantidad de registros es: 000
C:\wamp64\www\CencolpSoft\Reporte\Reporte.php:49:float 2.7
C:\wamp64\www\CencolpSoft\Reporte\Reporte.php:50:float 2

Y en ese caso ya no puedo hacer ninguna operacion matematica

Comment: ¿Cuando el número convertido te da `0`, si haces un `echo $total1[0];` imprime un valor distinto de `0`?  ... No entiendo por qué el uso de `gettype` ¿?

Comment: El uso de gettype lo sugerí para que descartara que fuese realmente el problema el tipo cómo lo indica en su pregunta.

Comment: perdona, no habia visto lo ultimo, pero gracias me sirvio muchisimo.